# How to run Coded UI Tests without Visual Studio 2010 Premium

Tags: visual-studio, licensing, build, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I want to ask you if it is possible to build and run coded ui tests without Visual Studio 2010 Premium installed?

Or can I just install Visual Studio 2010 Premium and use it command line without licensing? I know it works, but is the license ok with that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you would need to license it. If you want to run the tests on a 'test' machine or 'build' machine without using VS to run them, then I would look at the Test Agent, Controller, and remote execution in the Test Sku's available from MS.