# Unable to load assembly 'Microsoft​.VisualStu​dio.TestTo​ols.UITest​ing' in Python

Tags: python, .net, load, assemblies, python.net

I have automated my whole framework in Ironpython and it's working pretty good and stable.

Recently, my company has implemented Drag and Drop functionality to automate.

I found one Dll( 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll') which has class mouse and that class has method called mouse.startdragging() and mouse.stopdragging().

But unfortunately, I am unable to add the reference of this Dll. I am getting following error

"  clr.AddReference("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting")
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting'.
   at Python.Runtime.CLRModule.AddReference(String name) in C:\Users\Barton\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\PySharp\trunk\pythonnet\src\runtime\moduleobject.cs:line 375 "

I would truly appreciate if anyone can help me, I am middle of my project

Answer (score 1):

The Coded UI libraries are not distributed with .NET. They come with Visual Studio Premium and up and the license does not allow you to distribute them.

[How to run Coded UI Tests without Visual Studio 2010 Premium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778871/how-to-run-coded-ui-tests-without-visual-studio-2010-premium)

You could license the libraries but this is financially impractical for most deployment scenarios. You should use a different method to achieve drag&drop.