# Mouse Automation with c#

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, mouseevent

Can we use `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse` for automation purpose in a program (Is it possible to use it with our normal application cording. Not for the testing. )

I want to automate some mouse movements in my program. Like we are doing in Microsoft UI automation. I am not going to create a test project.

If this is possible please advice me.

Is mouse simulation is possible with UI automation?

**EDIT**
Since this is (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse`) used for coded UI testing I want to know is it possible to use in normal programming purpose. Because this `Mouse` class has some of useful methods which I need.

Comment: is your program winforms, wpf, asp?  Please provide a few more details.

Comment: @David: it is a WPF programme. (.net 3.5 framework )

Comment: do you actually need to move the mouse, or do you just need to click on things?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185916/move-mouse-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be technically possible to use it from an application. I believe all you need to do is make sure you call `Playback.Initialize` before using the `Mouse` class. However, I believe the license for VS will not allow you to redistribute the required dlls with your application.

UI Automation does not have facilities for low level input simulation.

I've use the [TestApi](http://testapi.codeplex.com/) project with some success to automate mouse and keyboard input when UI Automation and the Coded UI api's could not be used. It is easy to accomplish moving and clicking the mouse with the the `Mouse` class there:

```
using Microsoft.Test.Input;
using System.Drawing;

Mouse.MoveTo(new Point(100, 200));
Mouse.Click(MouseButton.Left);
```

Comment: Your answer is perfectly ok. I need another advice from you. When I tried to do this in .net 3.5, it says "The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'", What assemble I need to add?

Comment: @NewDeveloper Probably Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll which is in visual studio's install directory. Sommething like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the mouse location is as simple as this :

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
```

You can also send click messages through the message loop using some pinvoke calls.

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2416762/410075) some time ago.

**EDIT**

As I thought, you wouldn't be able to distribute your application with the Coded UI libraries without an additional license :

[How to run Coded UI Tests without Visual Studio 2010 Premium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778871/how-to-run-coded-ui-tests-without-visual-studio-2010-premium)

Comment: I want to know is it possible to use Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse in programming. Because this normally use for testing.

Comment: We had some problems with deploying test code on our continuous integration server without installing Visual Studio on it. Unless I am wrong, these libraries are licensed with Visual Studio Premium and up only. You probably don't have the right to deploy it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx